# Reorder a unique list to another by movings in the original list

Tags: list, algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic, unique

I'm looking for an algorithm in any imperative programming language to reorder a unique list to another by movings in the original list.

**Input:**

```
items       = [a, b, c, d, e]
sampleItems = [b, c, e, d, a]
```

**Output:**

```
items   =     [b, c, e, d, a]
```

Sets of items in *items* and *sampleItems* is equal.

Reordering should be performed by movings in the original list (*items*).

```js
void Move(int oldIndex, int newIndex)
{
  Item item = items[oldIndex];
  items.RemoveAt(oldIndex);
  items.Insert(item, newIndex);
}
```

So *items* list saves its uniqueness in the all period of reordering.

The algorithm should be as efficient as possible, not create additional data structures such as a dictionary, and have a minimal amount of movings and minimal complexity.

A brute force approach is a bubble sorting by new indices. But it requires either the creation of a dictionary (key: item,  value: new index) or numerous enumeration on the sample list (*sampleItems*). I'm looking for something more efficient.

I tried the following algorithm (C#), it works correctly, but not efficient since it creates a dictionary and has O(n^2) complexity. The processing of 10001 items takes about 9 sec. It is slow:

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp14
{
 class Program
 {
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   ObservableCollection<Item> items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

   int count = 10001;

   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
    items.Add(new Item(i));
   }

   Random random = new Random();   
   ObservableCollection<Item> sampleItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>(items.OrderBy(i => random.Next()));
   
   Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
   Dictionary<Item, int> oldIndeces = new Dictionary<Item, int>();
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
    oldIndeces.Add(items[i], i);
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
    int oldIndex = oldIndeces[sampleItems[i]];
    items.Move(oldIndex, i);

    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
    {
     Item item = items[j];
     int oldIndex1 = oldIndeces[item];
     if (oldIndex1 <= oldIndex)
      oldIndeces[item] = oldIndex1 + 1;
    }
   }

   Debug.Assert(sampleItems.SequenceEqual(items));
   stopwatch.Stop();
   Console.WriteLine($"Done in {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
   Console.ReadLine();
  }
 }

 public class Item
 {
  public Item(int num)
  {
   Num = num;
  }

  private int Num { get; }

  #region Overrides of Object

  public override string ToString()
  {
   return Num.ToString();
  }

  #endregion
 }
}
```

Output:

> Done in 9123ms

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation without dictionary:

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp14
{
 class Program
 {
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   ObservableCollection<Item> items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

   int count = 10001;

   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
    items.Add(new Item(i));
   }

   Random random = new Random();   
   ObservableCollection<Item> sampleItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>(items.OrderBy(i => random.Next()));
   
   Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
   int oldIndex = 0;
   Item sampleItem;
   Item nextSampleItem = null;
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
    sampleItem = sampleItems[i];
    if (i < count - 1) nextSampleItem = sampleItems[i + 1];

    if (i == 0)
    {
     for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
     {
      if (sampleItem == items[j])
       oldIndex = j;
     }
    }

    items.Move(oldIndex, i);

    for (int j = i + 1; j < count; j++)
    {
     if (items[j] == nextSampleItem)
     {
      oldIndex = j;
     }
    }
   }

   Debug.Assert(sampleItems.SequenceEqual(items));
   stopwatch.Stop();
   Console.WriteLine($"Done in {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
   Console.ReadLine();
  }
 }

 public class Item
 {
  public Item(int num)
  {
   Num = num;
  }

  private int Num { get; }

  #region Overrides of Object

  public override string ToString()
  {
   return Num.ToString();
  }

  #endregion
 }
}
```

> Done in 533ms

This implementation works for non-unique lists too.